# Parameterized authorization credentials in web activity ADF

Tags: azure, authentication, parameters, authorization, azure-data-factory

I try to parametrize Web activity authorization. I have created two parameters User_Name and Pass, type of String. Assign parameters value to auth. credential with this part of json code in adf pipeline.

[image]

Properties in the web activity settings tab look like this.

[image]

I have got authentication error when trying to execute the pipeline, the user name property has got a correct value but the password was bad. This is error code message:  *"errorCode": "2108"*
*Authentication_InvalidCredentials","message":"The server has rejected the client credentials.*

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended practice to parameterize passwords or secrets. Store all connection strings in Azure Key Vault instead, and parameterize the Secret Name.

Comment: Is that mean not possible or just not recommended but possible?

Comment: It's the former, not possible

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, things that can have parameterized content are those fields which accept dynamic input.

These tend to have text *Add dynamic content [Alt+P]* text below them when you click on the input box.

[image]

User name and password in basic authentication cannot be parameterized directly but there is a way.

Choose Authentication as None in the settings but provide authentication information in header whose value can be parameterized.
See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you give me more details about Authorization node format in header. Is it "Basic UserName:Pass" or "Basic AccessToken" or ...?

Comment: This will depend on the API endpoint accepting the request. In my example I had it set up as per https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/basic-authentication/

Comment: but it is ususally the same for most clients username:password encoded in Base 64. So i'd suggest you follow the process in the link above and encode username:password text combination and send in Header